# Disaster Recovery for ADFS servers

Tags: azure

Can I use Azure Site Recovery to perform DR for Active Directory Federation  &  Proxy servers across Azure Regions and can we do ASR replication for Domain controllers

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as your Azure ADFS installation would run inside VMs you can replicate them to other regions. Azure Site Recovery is application agnostic.